# Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "email@example.com" using 2 possible authenticators

Tags: email, laravel, laravel-4, exchange-server, swiftmailer

I'm trying to connect to our internal MS Exchange server in order to send out emails from our Laravel application.

In the `mail.php` config I have the following settings:

```
Driver = smtp
Host = Our exchange IP address which is correct
Port = 25
Encryption = tls
```

The user credentials are correct but I still receive the following error:

> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "email@example.com" using 2 possible authenticators

We are using the full email as the username, as if we don't then SwiftMailer complains, and I receive:

```
Undefined offset: 1
```

This occurs in the `getDomainAndUsername($name)` method, as it's trying to explode the username using the `@` symbol.

Any ideas what might be going on here? Has anyone dealt with using SwiftMailer in Laravel connecting to an MS Exchange server?

Comment: I had the same thing happen. It started yesterday out of the blue.

Comment: Still completely unable to log in via SwiftMailer using SSL or TLS, though we have found a temporary solution by not using any encryption but base64 encoded plain text (AUTH LOGIN), restricting the login to specific IP's. This seems to be working OK.

Comment: Are you positive you have TLS encryption on port 25?  It's not 587 or 465?

Comment: @BayssMekanique We've tried a ton of configuration options on a myriad different ports, nothing works except the above unfortunately.

Comment: Try Microsoft's connectivity helper to make sure your settings are all correct. https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/

Comment: I once connected swiftmailer to an exchange server. I encounterd that same problem. Seems strange, but it worked after leaving the encryption & user & pass empty.

Comment: Check if you have openssl enabled in your php.ini